# Binding parameters to OLEDB command throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection, oledb

I am using AS 400 OLEDB with .NET. It uses '?' instead of '@param to bind parameters with a command
Now there is a situation where the command is like

```
SELECT ...
FROM
   (SELECT ... 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnName) as RowNum
    FROM Employees e
   ) as DerivedTableName
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
```

Now my command becomes

```
    SELECT ...
FROM
   (SELECT ... 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnName) as RowNum
    FROM Employees e
   ) as DerivedTableName
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ? AND (? + ?) - 1
```

Now when I bind parameters like

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?",startRowIndex));
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", startRowIndex));
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", MaximumRows));
```

It throws error

```
SQL0417: Combination of parameter markers not valid.
Cause . . . . . :   The statement string specified as the object of a PREPARE statement contains a predicate or expression where parameter markers have been used as operands of the same operator.  The following restrictions apply to the use of parameter markers: -- Both the operands in a predicate cannot be parameter markers. For example, specifying predicates of the form:    ? = ?      or    ? = ( SELECT ? FROM x ) are not valid.
```

How do I bind parameters in this situation ? I want to avoid sql injection :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the names of the parameters

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@startRowIndex",startRowIndex));
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@startRowIndex2", startRowIndex));
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@MaximumRows", MaximumRows));
```

but leave the SQL as is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. In OLEDB the parameters go with index and symbol '?' and not with name '@param'. That works on SQLServer. Any clue?

Comment: He is, but problem is still there because of two parameters inside a single block (?+?). What do you do in access to get away with that ? Check my error description above.

Comment: Bump, anybody with OLEDB experience ?

Comment: "Both the operands in a expression cannot be parameter markers. For example, specifying an expression of the form: ? + ? is not valid." Can't you add the two values instead of doing it in SQL?

Comment: hey I can, but that would require me to concatenate the values with query like where '+(parameter1+parameter2)+'

Problem being, I want to bind the parameters in form of parametrized query.