# How to insert a record with a primary key in ms access database c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I am using the following command for inserting a record in an MS Access database:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table1 values('" + Name + "','" +
Symbol + "','" + D + "','" + Red + "','" + RedBuy + "','" + RedSell + "','" + 
SBIntraBuy + "','" + SBTR1Buy + "','" + SBTR2Buy + "','" + SBTR3Buy + "','" + 
SBIntraSell + "','" + SBTR1Sell + "','" + SBTR2Sell + "','" + SBTR3Sell + "','" + RSTL
+ "','" + Green + "');", con);
```

I want to add a column before Name called CustomerId with a Primary key. I don't know how to insert it with primary key. What i should add in my command for primary key?

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Check [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4uKG.jpg) for screen shot of the table layout.

Comment: Is the `CustomerId` field auto-incrementing?  Can we see your table structure please.

Comment: one min please while i take a screenshot

Comment: Yup, it's auto increment (or autonumber). Go ahead and try my answer :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your key is auto increment, then you don't need to. The database will do it for you. If your key is not auto increment, consider changing it. It's really neat!

Also, please consider using [binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210414/binding-parameters-to-oledb-command-throws-error) instead of building a full insert query.

Suppose the following table:

```
Table1
PK (auto_increment)
Name
Symbol
```

What you will want to do is:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table1 (Name,Symbol) values (?,?)");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Name",Name));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Symbol",Symbol));
```

or (safer):

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table1 (Name,Symbol) values (@Name,@Symbol)");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Name",Name));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Symbol",Symbol));
```

And finally:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Can C# accept ? as parameters.  I've always seen the variable used in the `Parameters.Add()` method; `@Name`, or `@Symbol` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Its Working but i cant vote you because i am not having sufficient reputations

Comment: @AdamWenger It works with ?, but it might be safer just in case to use a named variable like `@Name`. And I only tested with dBase, so maybe it's engine dependant...

Comment: @AdamWenger Yes, DbCommands can use parameters without names (the ? in the command text). Some DbCommands, do NOT support parameter names. In these cases, you must order the parameters properly. IMO, this adds code debt, so with any DbCommands that do support parameter names, use them.