# Issue running INSERT command using OleDbCommand in C#

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I have the following which looks to be ok, but for some reason it's throwing `ORA-00936: missing expression`

```
...
var query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (@id, @filepath, @filename, @filesize, @md5)";

using (var insertCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
{
    insertCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
    {
        new OleDbParameter("@id", FindItemId(filePath)),
        new OleDbParameter("@filepath", filePath),
        new OleDbParameter("@filename", new FileInfo(filePath).Name),
        new OleDbParameter("@filesize", new FileInfo(filePath).Length),
        new OleDbParameter("@md5", GetMd5Hash(filePath))
    });
    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
```

[image]

In debug, I can see the parameter values are binded correctly. So what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use try catch you will get proper error

Comment: @HiteshThakor The image above is generated from a try catch exception.

Answer (score 1):

What Mick said above is correct.

OleDbCommand and OdbCommand does not support named parameters and uses the ? placeholder instead, so the order of the parameters is important. However, you can give names to its parameters instead of using ?, for readability purposes like below:

```
...
var query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

using (var insertCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
{
insertCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
insertCmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
{
    new OleDbParameter("@id", FindItemId(filePath)),
    new OleDbParameter("@filepath", filePath),
    new OleDbParameter("@filename", new FileInfo(filePath).Name),
    new OleDbParameter("@filesize", new FileInfo(filePath).Length),
    new OleDbParameter("@md5", GetMd5Hash(filePath))
});
insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210414/binding-parameters-to-oledb-command-throws-error)

Apparently need to use `?` for binding with OLEDB in ORACLE 0_o

The following works..

```
...
var query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

using (var insertCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
{
    insertCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
    {
        new OleDbParameter("?", FindItemId(filePath)),
        new OleDbParameter("?", filePath),
        new OleDbParameter("?", new FileInfo(filePath).Name),
        new OleDbParameter("?", new FileInfo(filePath).Length),
        new OleDbParameter("?", GetMd5Hash(filePath))
    });
    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
```